# logarithmic calculation issue in python jupyter notebook

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

In jupyter notebook i tried to execute below code:

```
from math import log2
-((25/50)*log2(25/50))+((25/50)*log2(25/50))
```

output which am receiving is 0.0

it should be 1, what is the issue???

Comment: brackets are not placed correctly i think should be like : `-(log2(25/50)*(25/50)+(25/50)*log2(25/50))`

Comment: Why would you expect a non-zero answer when the input is `-x+x`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is actually a math issue. not programming. the last thing must come in mind is that python is working wrong!
both sides of `+` are equal and one of them has multiplied by -1. so it is like you are calculating this: `-x+x` and it is equal to 0.
I guess you have this in mind: `-((25/50) * log2(25/50) + (25/50) * log2(25/50))`. In this case, you will have an equation like:`-(x+x)`. so you will get 1 for the answer.

```
>>> from math import log2
>>> -((25/50) * log2(25/50)) + ((25/50) * log2(25/50))
# 0.0
>>> -((25/50) * log2(25/50) + (25/50) * log2(25/50))
# 1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Why should the answer be `1`? The answer to this is `0`. If `x = ((25/50)*log2(25/50))` then you are doing `-x + x` which is always 0.

Comment: i am doing -(x+x). Is there any syntax issue?

Comment: got it , it was syntax issue. i intend to d this -(((25/50)*log2(25/50))+((25/50)*log2(25/50))).